# Xcode 14 iOS simulator stuck on black screen

Tags: xcode, macos-ventura

When trying to run the default iOS test App from Xcode, the simulator gets stuck and just shows a black screen. I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.1 with Xcode version 14.2, the simulated iOS device has iOS version 16.2.

I created a new iOS App project in Xcode, changed nothing (everything as default) and tried to run it. It compiled successfully and starts the simulator (which shows the apple logo for a short time) but then hangs on a black screen.

Comment: Do not include the answer in the question. The answer goes in the Answer field. (Also I don't believe your answer is right, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks, I changed it. But reinstalling XCode still solved it for me, so I thought it might be helpulf for other people.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question @JakobS. Ive just had the same issue and your findings pointed me in the right direction to fix the issue. The cause is where XCode is configured to point to Xcode command line tools from another copy of xcode (Xcode -> Settings -> Locations -> Command Line Tools). You'll see an exclamation mark next to the setting. Xcode uses "xcrun" from this folder to launch the simulator - clearly it doesn't like mixing versions, but the simulator is not vocal enough.
My "mistake" was that I had "Xcode.app" from a manual download, and "Xcode14.app" from the app store.

Comment: I fixed the issue by updating Xcode via App Store (which was my source of origin). Originally I wanted to have two versions of Xcode, but when I had one from App Store (older version), then I downloaded 14.2 via Developer's website, issue popped up.

Comment: For me, I downloaded Xcode and then installed it from the app store. All was fine except that the simulator screen was black.

The fix was to move the code application to the bin,
Empty bin,
Reinstall XCode